# Smallest segment after whose removal all elements are distinct

Tags: algorithms, binary-search

I am interested in the following [problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1208/problem/B):

> We are given an array of integers and we need to find the **size** of smallest subsegment such that after removing it all elements in the array are distinct.

How to solve this problem using binary search in $O(n\log n)$? I tried to read various submissions which use binary search, for example [this one](https://codeforces.com/contest/1208/submission/59494540), but I couldn't understand them.

My attempt - I solved this problem in $O(n^2\log n)$ using brute force, but I want to know how to apply binary search to solve this problem in $O(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you can check whether the answer is at most some value $m$ in time $O(n)$. Applying binary search on $m$, you obtain an $O(n\log n)$ solution.

How do you check whether the answer is at most $m$ in time $O(n)$? The idea is to slide a window of length $m$ across your array. If at some point all elements outside the window are distinct, then we are done.

How do we implement this sliding algorithm? Let $A$ be the original array. We initialize an array $M$ which contains the histogram of the elements in $A_{m+1},\ldots,A_n$, as well as the number of distinct elements $x$. If $x = n-m$ then we are done. Otherwise, we modify $M$ to contain the histogram of $A_1,A_{m+2},\ldots,A_n$:

- We remove one copy of the element $A_{m+1}$ from $M$. If the new count of this element is $0$, then we decrease $x$.
- We add one copy of the element $A_1$ to $M$. If the new count of this element is $1$, then we increase $x$.

In this way, we can update $M$ in time $O(1)$ per shift.

The solution you link to does all this, apart from maintaining $x$; this is done automatically by the C++ map data structure.

Another point is the time complexity of this solution, which might depend on your exact computation model.

Comment: I did not understood applying binary search part of the submission .I mean i know binary search on sorted array but how binary search is applied on m i didn't understood .

Comment: That’s a great thing for you to work out.